# unresolved reference during calling a function

Tags: python

I keep getting "Unresolved Reference" error when, I'm trying to call function

here is code for area of circle

```
#area of circle
def arc(a,r):
    a=3.14 * (radius**2)
    return arc

radius=int(input("Enter Radius: "))
area_of_circle=arc(a,r)
print("Area of circle: {}".format(arc))
```

Comment: Please include the traceback of the error you're running into.

Comment: You're referring to variables that aren't in scope in several places in your code. I'd recommend doing a close reading of the code you wrote to make sure that you're referencing, passing, and returning the right variables.

Comment: Also your `arc` function should only take 1 argument (`r`).

Comment: the arc function is returning arc (the function) not a (the area). The print statement is also printing arc (the function) not area_of_circle

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in here, I'll step through each and explain what's happening.

The first two issues occur in your `arc()` function. I'll write comments above each offending line:

```py
def arc(a,r):
    # What is `radius`? That's not defined in this function!
    a=3.14 * (radius**2)
    # You're returning a reference to the arc() function from the arc() function?
    return arc
```

The next two issues are in the main area of your program. Again, I'll write comments above the offending lines:

```py
radius=int(input("Enter Radius: "))
# What is `a`? What is `r`? You haven't defined those names!
area_of_circle=arc(a,r)
# `arc` is a function, so what do you expect to happen here? 
print("Area of circle: {}".format(arc))
```

To clean this up, you need to make sure every name references a valid variable, and that you're using functions and variables correctly. In your particular program, functions should be defined and called, not returned from functions or passed around like variables in `.format()` statements. Variables should be defined and given a valid value.

There are a few other errors that may arise once you clean those issues up, but I'm hoping you'll be able to solve those once you have most of the issues fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed up the variables/names/labels in your code:

```
# area of circle
def area_of_circle(radius):
    area = 3.14 * (radius ** 2)
    return area


radius = int(input("Enter Radius: "))
area_of_circle = area_of_circle(radius)
print("Area of circle: {}".format(area_of_circle))
```